# how to check database user permission on fmp database using JAVA

Tags: java, filemaker

I want to know how to run FileMaker(FMP pro) database command in java. I have got the connection to database,but not sure how to execute below query.

Get(AccountPrivilegeSetName)

ref:
http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/func_ref2.32.4.html#1051898

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: @hveiga, it is simple jdbc connection steps. I Want to know sql query string to form to execute the below FMP command in java

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a calculation field in FileMaker to return as the result of the JDBC query. This is because you cannot call functions via JDBC, you can only retrieve field values.

Comment: HI Sam, how do I write a simple sql dummy statement that returns 1 from a table that works using JDBC?

Comment: You'll need to query an actual table. If the table has no records, you'll get an empty response. You might consider creating a simple one-record table for this purpose, and just do `select dummyField from dummyTable`.

Comment: Thanks Sam Barnum for  your response, I am query like below two queries but there is no response from the fmp(still running), if the query is wrong, it was perfectly saying syntax error.          SELECT max(CUST_ID) FROM CUST_MARKER
SELECT 1 FROM CUST_MARKER WHERE 1=1

Comment: i mean trying it from java stmt.executeQuery()